# Ninject multiple bindings depending on ctor parameter name

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Let's assume I have interfaces like the following:

```
public interface ISomething { };

public interface IResolver
{
    string ResolveBy(ISomething something);
}
```

Now I have two resolver types; one that delivers the best solution, but has a chance to fail and one resolver, that does always return a solution, which should act as a fallback strategy:

```
public class UnsafeResolver : IResolver
{
    Random random = new Random();

    public string ResolveBy(ISomething something)
    {
        if (random.NextDouble() > 0.5)
        {
            return "best solution ever!";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("something went wrong...");
        }
    }
}

public class SafeResolver : IResolver
{
    public string ResolveBy(ISomething something)
    {
        return "fallback solution";
    }
}
```

Now I want to combine both resolver within a *safeguarded* composition decorator:

```
public class SafeguardedResolver : IResolver
{
    private readonly IResolver unsafeResolver;
    private readonly IResolver safeResolver;

    // This is the problem with Ninject: Two parameters with same interface...
    public SafeguardedResolver(IResolver unsafeResolver, IResolver safeResolver)
    {
        // guards omitted!
        this.unsafeResolver = unsafeResolver;
        this.safeResolver = safeResolver;
    }

    public string ResolveBy(ISomething something)
    {
        try
        {
            return unsafeResolver.ResolveBy(something);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return safeResolver.ResolveBy(something);
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: How can I realize the binding with Ninject **without** using [Named Binding](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) Strategies? I do not want any dependencies to the container in my domain classes, so the proposed solution does not work for me

And of course without changing the ctor to `IEnumerable<IResolver>` - I want two separate **clearly named** parameters!

Why is it not possible to define the binding via the names of the parameters? For example something like this:

```
Bind<IResolver>().To<SafeguardedResolver>();
Bind<IResolver>().To<UnsafeResolver>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<SafeguardedResolver>()
    .AsParameter("unsafeResolver");
Bind<IResolver>().To<SafeResolver>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<SafeguardedResolver>()
    .AsParameter("safeResolver");
```

Isn't it possible to get the names of a parameter with reflection?

I hope somebody can give me an answer, how to solve that (perhaps by using another DI framework?) or why this is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want any dependencies to the container in my domain classes

You can use named bindings without referencing the container from your class library, here is how you can do it:

```
StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel
    .Bind<IResolver>()
    .To<SafeguardedResolver>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("unsafeResolver", c => c.Kernel.Get<IResolver>("unsafe"))
    .WithConstructorArgument("safeResolver", c => c.Kernel.Get<IResolver>("safe"));

kernel
    .Bind<IResolver>()
    .To<UnsafeResolver>()
    .Named("unsafe")
    .BindingConfiguration.IsImplicit = true;

kernel
    .Bind<IResolver>()
    .To<SafeResolver>()
    .Named("safe")
    .BindingConfiguration.IsImplicit = true;
```

Here is how you would do the same thing with [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/):

```
var result = new SafeguardedResolver(new UnsafeResolver(), new SafeResolver());
```

The simplicity of Pure DI in cases like these is one of the reasons why IMO [it is better than using a container](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html).

Comment: I must admit that I have also read Marc Seeman's Blog regarding his "change of mind" towards pure DI, which he has called "poor man's DI" in his brilliant book. I just started to use Ninject for one project to get an impression. Imho it is difficult to judge, what works better. Imho there is a lack of **enough complex** examples for both approaches. I am still wondering, what good patterns for pure DI are.